# How to find the level of the particular node(top to bottom,ascending order,two child each) in tree structure?

Tags: php, math, data-structures, binary-tree, nodes

I have tree structure like where each node must have two child nodes to go further
so how can I find out by number that it will be on xyz level(start from top(1) to ascending order) in the tree.
I need Mathematics formula so i can apply it in PHP code.

The image of my tree structure

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZUs6.png]

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Comment: you use a class 'node' to store the values?

Comment: @ryan i solved it by adding 1 into parents level number while inserting child level in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so someone help me to solve the problem.
The solution is add +1 into parents level which i can get through database & if the parent is on the top of the tree give it default value "1" in the mysql.

first i thought it is all about mathematics but it is become too easy by just apply a simple logic.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using another variable 'level' in the node class, and find the level while inserting the node. So it will be easier to find it later. Just take the particular node and take it's level variable.

Comment: probably i did the same .i took the parent level from the top & add +1 into childs level cell while inserting problem is solved.

Comment: yea, but it depends on the data structure too. If he is using just 1 array, and he wants to find the level of the 10-th position he can do like:
cnt=0;
10/2=5  (cnt++)
5/2=2    (cnt++)
2/2=1    (cnt++)
1/2=0    (cnt++)
so in the 4th level

Comment: may be.but the my comment answer is working great & there will be not much calculation even if there will be tree with so many nodes